# How to best share resources between multiple Cakephp applications?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

2 otherwise independent Cakephp applications are to share some mostly presentation related resources, e.g.

- CSS files
- Javascript files
- Custom Helpers
- Elements
- Layouts

For the helpers, it would be sufficient to create a plugin that can be used in both applications. But I could not figure out if there is a way to share application-wide layout and css files for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme:

```
CSS
Javascript
Elements
Layouts
```

Plugin:

```
Helpers
```

If you are already using a theme, you can make a plugin with the assets and use it like

```
echo $this->Html->css('AssetPlugin.something');
```

You can bundle it as a standalone plugin and use git submodules to include in various projects.

Answer (score 0):

If its sufficient for the helpers, why don't you just make a plugin called 'Presentations' and put everything you need relating to the presentation code into that?